# Returning value from function without completing function

Tags: java, multithreading, return

My function is to send an HTTP request to a server and get a response. It looks like :

```
public Acknowledgement function() {
     Acknowledgement ack = new Acknowledgement("received");
     //send http request and get response
     return ack;
}
```

The purpose of the Acknowledgement is to inform the caller that function() has been successfully called and processing has been started.

I want to return acknowledgement before sending HTTP request. One way is to use separate thread(implementing Runnable) for sending request and getting response. But Threads have been  pretty old. What are other latest alternative to threads to achieve this.

Comment: Threads aren't old... Lots of everyday, modern  apps use them

Comment: There is no alternative. You probably want to take a look at ``ExecutorService`` that lets you run ``Runnable``s. But guess what's really happening: Threads.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a callback listener, like:

```
interface LifecycleListener {
    void onStarting();
}

public Acknowledgement function(LifecycleListener listener) {         
     listener.onStarting();
     ...
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many things exist in Java for almost 20 years. Doesn't mean that we should stop using String, or Integer do we?

But you are correct insofar that there are (slightly) newer **abstractions** on top of bare metal threads.

So, concepts to study would be [ExecutorServices](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) and things like [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Using threads directly; especially in conjunction with low level primitives such as wait/notify is probably not the first choice in 2017; you would rather look into the aforementioned ExecutorService; or even going one step further and learn about frameworks like [RXJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki).

Answer (score -1):

threads are not old,if you want to do it better,you can use thread pool to manage them